# Regular expression to accept numbers up to 5 digits and decimals

Tags: java, regex

`\d{0,5}\.\d{0,6}` Does not accept numbers without a decimal. How do i get it to ignore the decimal place when not entered

Comment: What kind of numbers do you want to accept? Is `.5` valid ? Or `1.`? If not then maybe it is worth changing some (or all) `{0` to `{1`.

Comment: At the moment i want it to accept .5

Answer (score 4):

Make the entire decimal group optional:

```
\d{0,5}(?:\.\d{0,6})?
```

This would match 0 to 5 digits, with or without a decimal point followed by another 0 to 6 digits.

We can add `?:` inside a capture group to tell the regex engine *not* to capture what is inside the parentheses.  In this case, without using `?:` the engine would have captured the optional decimal point and subsequent digits.  Turning off capture could improve performance of the regex, which is why you will see this being discussed often with regex questions on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Maybe, (?: ) instead of () will be better?

Comment: Thank you, i will test this out

Comment: @Gangnus what does that do?

Comment: It will be better with anchors. Like that it matches `abc123.456xyz`

Comment: @b.d A **capturing group** () remembers (**captures**) the substring that matches to content of (). (?: ) is a **non-capturing group**, it only holds some part of regex together, what we really need.

Comment: @Toto It matches only that number part in abc123.456xyz. Question does not say, what surrounding of a number is allowed.

Comment: @Toto Not exactly.  If using `String#matches(pattern)` then it would only return true if the entire string matches the pattern.  For `String#matches()` the `^` and `$` anchors are redundant.

Comment: OK, but you may add a notice that this regex is for `matches` and if you're using `find` you have to add hanchors.

Comment: @Toto Again, not necessarily.  If the OP were trying to find all such numbers in a string, then you also would not want anchors.  Really, the OP should have clarified better what is wanted here.

Comment: This will also accept empty string (not sure if it is acceptable or not, but it is worth mentioning).

Comment: @Pshemo yes i want it to accept the empty string also

Comment: Would this have to change much to use in a html pattern?

Comment: @b.d When dealing with HTML you should probably be using a parser, not a regex alone.

Answer (score 0):

`/(\d{0,5})(\.\d{0,5})*/` you can also use this

Comment: Sorry instead of `*` use `?` `/(\d{0,5})(\.\d{0,5})?/` ,thanks for pointing out. @Toto